# Fire method on Main Thread from other Threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

### Issue

---

I am using multi-threading inside my application and the way it works is that i have an array that contains 22 string which stand for some file names:

```
Public ThreadList As String() = {"FSANO1P", "FJBJB1P", "COPOR1P", "FFBIVDP", "FFCHLDP", "FFDBKDP", "FFDREQP", "FFINVHP", "FFJMNEP", "FFPIVHP", "FFUNTTP", "FJBJM1P", "FJBJM2P", "FJBNT2P", "FPPBE9P", "FTPCP1P", "FTTEO1P", "FTTRQ1P", "FJBJU1P", "FTTEG1P", "FFJACPP", "XATXTDP"}
```

I then loop through the array and create a new thread for each file:

```
For Each mThreadName As String In ThreadList                            
    Dim mFileImportThread = New FileImportThreadHandling(mThreadName, mImportGuid, mImportDate, Directory_Location, mCurrentProcessingDate, mRegion)
Next
```

So inside the new thread 'FileImportThreadHandling' it will call a method by starting a new thread:

```
mThread = New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
mThread.Name = "FileImportThreadHandling"
mThread.Start()
```

Then in 'DoWork' it will determine what file is current in question and will run the code related to the file.

After the code has ran for the file I want to report this back to the main thread. Can somebody give me a solution please.

Comment: Why aren't you using Tasks and `async/await`? They exist so that you can *avoid* working with raw threads

Comment: You need to get the main thread to listen for a "thread completed" event which is fired from the thread when it completes.

Comment: You can report progress, send messages etc from a thread/task using the `Progress<T>` class which was built for exactly this purpose. Multiple tasks/threads can publish messages which are handled by a method running in the original thread. Most .NET classes accept the `IProgress<T>` interface

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you have an example of how I could implement this?

Comment: @ChrisF Because the thread wont be completed until all the threads have been completed. So i cannot use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Take a look at this snippet:

```
Sub Main()
    mThread = New Thread(AddressOf doWork)
    mThread.Name = "FileImportThreadHandling"
    mThread.Start()
End Sub


Sub doWork()
    'do a lot of hard work
    workDone(result)
End Sub


Delegate Sub workDoneDelegate(result As Integer)
Sub workDone(abilita As Boolean, Optional src As Control = Nothing)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New workDoneDelegate(AddressOf workDone), {result})
    Else
        'here you're on the main thread
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how i can use them in my situation.

Comment: Create a delegate for the function you want to call and use it inside the thread

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might give you some ideas.  Note the use of Async and Task.  You will need a form with two buttons, and a label.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public ThreadList As String() = {"FSANO1P", "FJBJB1P", "COPOR1P", "FFBIVDP", "*******", "FFJACPP", "XATXTDP"}

    'note Async keyword on handler
    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Button1.Enabled = False
        Dim running As New List(Of Task)

        For Each tskName As String In ThreadList
            'start new task
            Dim tsk As Task
            tsk = Task.Run(Sub()
                               For x As Integer = 1 To 10
                                   Dim ct As Integer = x
                                   'simulate code related to the file
                                   Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

                                   'report to the UI
                                   Me.Invoke(Sub()
                                                 Label1.Text = String.Format("{0}  {1}", tskName, ct)
                                             End Sub)
                               Next
                           End Sub)

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) 'for testing delay between each start

            running.Add(tsk)
        Next

        'async wait for all to complete
        For Each wtsk As Task In running
            Await wtsk
        Next

        Button1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'test UI responsive during test
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is a windows service therefore i cannot have buttons

Comment: Did you say that in your OP?

Answer (score 0):

Using Actions and a callback to track remaining operations. (Simplified your class for my example)

```
Public ThreadList As String() = {"FSANO1P", "FJBJB1P", "COPOR1P", "FFBIVDP", "FFCHLDP"}
Private actionCounter As Integer = 0
Private lockActionCounter As New Object()

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Starting...")
    For Each mThreadName As String In ThreadList
        Dim mFileImportThread = New FileImportThreadHandling(mThreadName)
        actionCounter += 1
        Call New Action(AddressOf mFileImportThread.DoWork).
            BeginInvoke(AddressOf callback, mThreadName)
    Next
    Console.Read()
End Sub

Private Sub callback(name As IAsyncResult)
    Dim remainingCount As Integer
    SyncLock lockActionCounter
        actionCounter -= 1
        remainingCount = actionCounter
    End SyncLock
    Console.WriteLine("Finished {0}, {1} remaining", name.AsyncState, actionCounter)
    If remainingCount = 0 Then Console.WriteLine("All done")
End Sub

Private Class FileImportThreadHandling
    Shared r = New Random()
    Private _name As String
    Public Sub New(name As String)
        _name = name
    End Sub
    Public Sub DoWork()
        Dim delayTime = (r).Next(500, 5000)
        Console.WriteLine("Doing {0} for {1:0}ms.", _name, delayTime)
        Thread.Sleep(delayTime)
    End Sub
End Class
```